# how to get the roles and permissions dinamically - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm trying to implement roles and permissions for my laravel API. I installed the package:

```
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-acl/3.0/introduction
```

It would be great if someone could explain to me how it works, all I want to do is get the permission when the user hits one API route.
I don't want to set the middleware in every route, because I'm going to do several routes and it would be a pain to set middleware every time, I want do it dynamically.

I tried to do it myself but it's not working. This is my code in Authserviceprovider:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();

    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));

    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));

    $permissions = Permission::with('roles')->get();

    foreach ($permissions as $permission)
    {
        $gate->define($permission->name, function (User $user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasPermission($permission);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm doing like this: https://github.com/laracasts/laravel-5-roles-and-permissions-demo/tree/master/app

Comment: "i don't want set the middleware in every route, because i'm going to do several routes and would be a pain set middleware every time" - You realise you don't have to set the middleware every time right? you can set it once within the web.php file and anything between the middleware will automatically be checked

Comment: I didn't know that, I'm still learning about Laravel

Comment: the file i'm using to set my routes is called api.php

Comment: I've posted an answer for you in relation of how to use middleware. This should be more than suitable for what you're trying to do. Any routes you don't want being checked by middleware, simply place it beneath the });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use middleware within your web.php / api.php file such as my example (web.php) below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['verified']], function () {
     Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

As my example shows, this will check an account is verified before allowing it to view '/'

**Updated**

This is almost irrelevant to the question above but as the Op asked a secondary question within the comments to my answer: here is my middleware code to show the Op how the middleware will function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $verified = Auth::user();

        if ($verified->verified == 0)
        {
            Auth::logout();

            Session::flash('error', "$verified->username, your email address hasn't been verified yet therefore you're unable sign in.");

            return Redirect('/login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to share from the Laravel docs, It should work perfectly :) Up

Comment: I use it in all of my projects too as I mainly make sites that have user roles etc so it works wonders.

Comment: I don't do Laravel anymore (and I miss it) but I was sure I've seen the group option in routes. Laravel always knows how to amaze me.

Comment: Haha yes, it's great to use. I was a strong user of PDO before I finally delved into Laravel this year. Safe to say it's all I use now.

Comment: ok, i understand now, and it looks great, but how i can check the permission to my route on that middleware?

Comment: @Leandro, anything between the middleware group will run the middleware first. Therefore based on my example above. If I wasn't verified and tried to view '/' the middleware would run, throw an error and redirect me elsewhere. However, if I was verified, the MWare would still run, see I am verified and then allow me to view the '/' page

Comment: @Leandro, I have edited the answer with the middleware example I gave so you can see how it'll work

Comment: @Leandro, if this has answered your question please mark it as your selected answer so if others read this in future they will know this was the answer.